# How to use Bing speech API with Asterisk?

Tags: speech-recognition, asterisk, ivr, bing-speech

I'm working to build an IVR with asterisk and I'm looking to use a speech recognition API. Can I use Bing speech API for speech recognition in asterisk passing through asterisk API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speech recognition work bad with 8khz sound(you can't get more then 8khz in telephony connected to POTS). Best working is google,but accuracy is terrible.

You can use this library for example https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

In asterisk you can use EAGI or Record app.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different experience with the Speech Cloud API used from the Asterisk.
First I think that the result could be different for each language.
We integrated IBM/Watson, Microsoft/Bing, Google/Speech in our Voximal Asterisk application (VoiceXML browser for Asterisk). We use them to create Voice Assistant and Virtal Agents (by connecting ChatBots, so we have an intensive usage). For the french language Microsoft seems to be better.
If you want to tests the Speech Cloud services from an Asterisk call, you can use them with Voximal on your Asterisk.